# Urgent SSH Local Port Redirection

Tags: ssh, port, redirection

I have a shell account but the admin has restricted ssh access to the server. The server is listening on 0.0.0.0:22 but the firewall blocks any incoming attempts to this port. He says he is doing maintenance but I don't believe him and I need to backup my stuff with ssh. My question is that: Is it possible to do this:

> Me (Wan IP) <-> Hosting Server
>   (tcp/8080) redirects to Hosting Server
>   (tcp/22)

I don't want to involve my own linux machine in this and I can only make use of ssh..

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you believe that the admin is doing maintenance?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to change the `Port` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to 8080 rather than to redirect from 8080 to 22 using SNAT via iptables.

Comment: Well but I don't have root privileges. This is the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run something on the hosting server that does the redirect.  If you can run ssh on the hosting server, you might be able to do it as

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:22 -N localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

If ssh has been disabled on the server I don't think port redirection will help.  You can always ssh -p 8080 but that doesn't mean that the ssh daemon will log you in.

If you do have access to the server that you want to put files, how are you logging on if not via ssh?  Can you get to a terminal?  If so I recommend using nc.  It's probably installed and pretty darn fast in my experience.

Run this on the machine you want to copy to:

```
nc -l 1234 > myfiles.tar.gz
```

This will redirect all input on port 1234 to the specified file.

And from the computer you are copying from:

```
nc <server name or ip> 1234 < myfiles.tar.gz
```

If you have access, there is a way.

Also, run nmap and see if ftp or file sharing ports are open.

Comment: nifty trick with `nc` :)